Google sheets and dymo printer
I need to export a csv from google sheets (UTF-8) that can be correctly read by my Dymo printer (ISO-8859-1). I have found there is an issue with special characters eg apostrophies not showing correctly. Is there a way to export a csv from google sheets using ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8 or some other work around?
I could export as xls - this works for the apostrophies, but then I need to delete rows every time or the dymo tries to print 999 lables...
I'd much prefer if I can get the csv to work.
